# Setting machineKey validationKey with IsolateApps option

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I have several webs that are load balanced via a load balancer.

I try to have forms authentication working if the user switches between servers. In the MSDN doku there is sentence:

```
If you add the IsolateApps modifier to the decryptionKey value, ASP.NET generates a unique encrypted key for each application using each application's application ID.
```

What does **application ID** mean here? Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

This relates to the forms authentication. When forms AUTH you can allocate an APP name to a given use case.
ISOLATE APPS, the default provider ensure the encrpted passwords a specific to an app.
ie  PASSWORD + SALT + Unique APP hash => selected encrytion algorithm.

You can use the default the Forms provider shipped with asp.net.
or roll your own.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

You can run the supplied exe  aspnet_regsql to create the DB the default MS  provider will use.
then for example in web.config.